# Spacing in QM-style integrals (differential first)

Tags: spacing

I'd like to write integrals with the differential first, the way physicists tend to: `$\int dx f(x)$`. The problem is that this puts an unsightly (to my eye) gap between the integral sign and the differential, and then puts the integrand much too close to the differential. I can solve this by writing something like `$\int \hskip -3pt dx\ f(x)$`, but that is hardly satisfactory.

What is the accepted way to do this? Where should I be looking?

Comment: Tear down the walls of prejudice, be adventurous, follow your instincts, and simply don't write as they do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 1):

As a physicist, I'd like to give you this:

```
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\!\mathrm{d}}
$\int \diff x f(x)$

\begin{equation}
    \int \diff x f(x)
\end{equation}
```

Although it doesn't look good in the $$-environment. Please note that it has to be d *x* and not *dx*.

Comment: But I think you don't get the space after the differential automatically. And you should care about how it looks in fractions and more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible definition, compared with the "default" output (`\displaystyle` is used only for showing the result without centering the formula). Note that you need different backspace in displays and in inline formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\pred[1]{
  \mathchoice{\mkern-6mu}{\mkern-1mu}{}{}
  d#1\,
}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\int_a^b \pred{x} f(x)$ \quad
$\displaystyle\int_a^b dx\, f(x)$

\bigskip

$\int_a^b \pred{x} f(x)$ \quad
$\int_a^b dx\, f(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you wrote this command, shouldn't be better to enclose `d#1` in a `\mathit{d#1}`? I'm not sure myself. The differential is written with two or more letters, but is *one object*.

Comment: @Manuel While "dx" is one object, it's still composed by two distinct symbols.

Comment: If you had written it with `\mathrm{d}` then I should think about it as an operator and then I haven't said anything. But since you wrote it in italic I think that may be `dx` should be written similar to the identity function which I write as `\mathit{id}` instead of `id`.

Comment: @Manuel I don't agree with this: `\mathit{id}` is good because the two letters don't have a separate meaning. In this case `x` should be the same `x` as in `f(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
\def\Int#1#2{\int \hskip -3pt d{#1}\ {#2}}
```

As far as I understand you want freezing the chosen skips.